# Alterar o código HttpParams para httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Eu tenho um código que conecta o json a um banco de dados mysql, mas o HttpParams está obsoleta na versão do java que estou usando, então eu gostaria de saber como faço ou qual melhor forma para colocar parâmetros novos e manter esse formato de pegar os dados, isso é de um login e senha que estou fazendo. Na pesquisa que fiz, o httpURLConnection seria uma boa alternativa?

Java para Android

O meu código:

```
 private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara o httpURLConnection pra mim funciona muito bem. Olha aí minha classe que tem o get e o post:

```
public class HttpConnections {
 //método get
public static String get(String urlString){
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resposta = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        resposta = buffer.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (urlConnection != null){
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            reader.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return resposta;
}
//post
public static String  performPostCall(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
} 
}
```

Depois é só chamar:

```
HttpConnections.get("sua url");//get
```

O post:

```
HashMap<String,String> login = new HashMap<>();
login.put("username","nome");
login.put("password","senha");
HttpConnections.performPostCall("sua url",login);
```

Os dois métodos retornam uma String com a resposta.
Exemplo no seu código:

```
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //aqui fica quase da mesma forma

    HashMap<String,String> login = new HashMap<>();
    login.put("username",params[1]);
    login.put("password",params[2]);//passe quantos campos você quizer

    String resposta = HttpConnections.performPostCall(params[0],login);//já retorna uma String, então seu código de converter para String é desnecessário       
    return resposta;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
    if(result.equals("") || result == null){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
    if(jsonResult == 0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    if(jsonResult == 1){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}    
private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){
    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedResult = 0;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedResult;
}
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, só gostaria de saber, neste seu código, não precisa usar o AsyncTask? E também, qual é a melhor forma em que  consigo passar os parametros do login e senha para o json? Estou entrando agora em java android e isso ta meio confuso pra mim, deve ser coisa simples. Obrigado

Comment: sim, precisa usar AsyncTask. Para passar os dados é bem parecido, basta   HashMap<String,String> login = new HashMap<>();
login.put("username","nome");
login.put("password","senha"); login.put("outro","outro"); . Editei o código, Acho que agora ficou melhor.

Comment: Muito bom cara, era exatamente o que eu precisava, vlw mesmo!

Comment: @FabianoAraujo Boa dica +1